# Validation date - dd/mm/yyyy - not working on all pc

Tags: asp.net

My format date is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

On most PC that is working fine. But on some PCs I have an error message during the validation:

> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_naisance, new { htmlAttributes =
>   new { @class = "form-control" } })
>
> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_naisance, "", new {
>   @class = "text-danger" })

In my web.config I have:

```
culture="fr-FR" and uiCulture="fr-FR"
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: The field xxxx must be a date.

https://garde.azurewebsites.net/Account/Register
Votre date de naissance